# Geting varchar width of a column that is actually used

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

How do I get the max amount of spaces used in a column?

For example:

```
ID   ColumnA
1    xxxxx
2    xxx
10   xxxxxxx
```

ID uses 2 spaces and ColumnA uses 7 spaces.

Comment: When you say "spaces" you mean characters? And including trailing actual spaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LEN()` counts the number of chars in a string.

```
SELECT MAX(LEN(CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(5)))) MAX_ID_SPACE,
       MAX(LEN(ColumnA)) Max_ColA_Space
FROM   TableName
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a1682/1)

Comment: Might need `SELECT MAX(LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(ColumnA))))`

Comment: I have another similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18993145/counting-spaces-before-and-after-a-decimal-point

Comment: `LEN` only counts the number of chars in a string correctly if that string contains no trailing spaces. Trailing spaces are ignored. Whether that is the desired behaviour or not for the OP who knows.

Comment: @MartinSmith good point, let's wait for the OP's feedback otherwise this will be deleted.

Comment: The trailing spaces shouldn't be counted.

Comment: @chris - So `LEN` is exactly what you need then.

Answer (score 1):

`Len(exp)` gives the length of an expression in *characters*, less any trailing blanks (`0x20`, Ascii `SP`).

`DataLength(exp)` gives the length of an expression in *bytes*, including any trailing blanks.

If you are using `char`, `varchar`, `binary` or `varbinary`, the only real difference is whether or not trailing blanks are included, since `char`/`varchar` are single-byte character strings, and `binary`/`varbinary` count in bytes anyway.

If you are using `nchar` or `nvarchar`, which are *double-byte* strings, so each character is two bytes and `len()` returns the length in *characters* while `datalength()` returns the length in bytes. You have to take the difference into account. So...

```
declare @some_string nvarchar(4000)

select @some_string = max(t.some_column)
from some_table t

declare
  @length_in_chars_excluding_trailing_spaces = len(        @some_string ) ,
  @length_in_chars_including_trailing_spaces = datalength( @some_string ) / 2
```

should do you.

One should take into account that fixed-length `char` and `nchar` fields are padded to their width with trailing spaces.