# Counting spaces before and after a decimal point

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have data set as a varchar(500), but I only know if it's numeric or character.

I need to count the max spaces of the length of a column AND the max spaces after a decimal point.

For Example:

```
ColumnA
1234.56789
123.4567890
```

would return 11 spaces total AND 7 spaces after the decimal.

It can be two separate queries.

Comment: Uhm, `LEN()` ? Have you tried to make your own research? What are its results?

Comment: spaces or characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT LEN(ColumnA )
      ,CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(ColumnA ))-1
FROM Table1
```

If a value has no decimal, the above will return -1 for the spaces after decimal, so you could use:

```
SELECT LEN(ColumnA)
      ,CASE WHEN ColumnA LIKE '%.%' THEN CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(ColumnA))-1
            ELSE 0
       END
FROM Table1
```

Demo of both: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a70ff/5/0)

If you just wanted the `MAX()` then you'd just wrap the above in `MAX()`:

```
SELECT MAX(LEN(ColumnA ))
      ,MAX(CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(ColumnA ))-1)
FROM Table1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT len(ColumnA), len(columnA) - charIndex('.',ColumnA)
FROM theTable
```

Comment: Note: If there is no decimal the length will be returned in both fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ColumnA, Len(ColumnA) As Total, LEN(SUBSTRING(ColumnA,CHARINDEX('.',ColumnA,LEN(ColumnA)) As Decimal
FROM TABLE
```